# Generating pseudo-random integers from a changing interval efficiently

Tags: c++, random, c++11, integer

I wrote the following class for generating random integers from a given interval `[lower, upper]`.

```
 class RandomInteger {

protected:

    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::default_random_engine randomEngine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;

public:

    RandomInteger(int64_t lower, int64_t upper);

    virtual ~RandomInteger();

    virtual int64_t generate();
};


RandomInteger::RandomInteger(int64_t lower, int64_t upper) : randomEngine(this->randomDevice()), distribution(lower, upper) {
}

RandomInteger::~RandomInteger() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int64_t RandomInteger::generate() {
    int64_t i = this->distribution(this->randomEngine);
    return i;
}
```

This is okay if the interval remains the same and multiple calls to `generate` are made. However, now my use case is generating integers from an interval which is always changing (the upper bound increases every time).

First and foremost, this needs to be fast. This has nothing to do with cryptography so very pseudo-random numbers are okay (and `std::random_device` is probably not needed). I would also like to avoid C style if possible and use modern C++11 style.

Can you suggest ways to do this efficiently?

Comment: Is changing the distribution not efficient enough? `uniform_int_distribution` is a very thin wrapper, there shouldn’t be any significant overhead. Also, why are the functions in your class `virtual`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph  They don't need to be virtual. Would making them nonvirtual result in significant speedup here? I've learned that the overhead for virtual method calls is very low. It's a strange situation: C++ claims to be an OOP language. OOP is very much about making your code extensible and reusable in the future. However, many C++ programmers constantly advise others to disable OOP (i.e. make methods nonvirtual) unless explicitly needed right now.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  "changing the distribution" would mean instantiating a new `std::uniform_int_distribution` with different parameters?

Comment: OOP is very overrated, C++ supports it but for the most part it has superior mechanisms (algorithm oriented programming) to solve a problem – see most of the standard library. virtual functions *do* have a significant cost, don’t be misled. Their actual overhead is relatively small but they pose a barrier to inlining, which may have much bigger implications on performance. Regarding your second question: yes, exactly. The cost of that should be effectively the same as assigning two integers (because internally that’s happening), nothing more.

Comment: In fact, if the compiler can deduce that you’re not changing the lower bound it *might* even be smart enough to only change the higher bound even if you construct a whole new distribution object every time. I wouldn’t count on this optimisation but it wouldn’t surprise me.

Comment: @cls FWIW you will also see many prominent people that use other so-called OOP languages tell you to "design for inheritance or forbid it". It sounds like the same idea to me. You cannot get reusability by simply slapping a keyword in there. Actual reusability and extensibility comes from design, not magically from language features (though lack of the right language features may hinder design).

Comment: @cls: That advice holds true for any language. "OOP language" is meaningless. Virtual functions are not a magic extensibility button- you need a whole lot more. Simple fact is, you don't need `virtual`, so don't use it.

Comment: @cls: who told you that "OOP" is the same as "making code extensible and reusable? It isn't. You can write extensible and reusable code without OOP, and you can write OOP code which is neither extensible nor reusable (and most of the OOP code I've seen falls into that category)

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times I've sat looking at some method, (usually on a GUI component), thinking 'why the **** did they make that static?

Comment: @cls I was gonna respond. However, I couldn't say it much better than `@`R.MF already did. Meanwhile, let me just commend you for actually ***asking the question*** instead of just :shrug: and thinking people are wrong. This is what sets people who (will) get it apart from the people who don't.

Comment: @jalf I didn't say that it is the same. When I said that "OOP is very much about extensibility and reusability", I meant that it has served this purpose for me time and again. I'm open to other approaches that work (and maybe better).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  The idea that reusability and extensibility comes more from design than from language features makes sense. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But now that we have discussed so much about the overhead of virtual methods, what about the overhead of `std::random_device`? Isn't accessing that a costly IO operation? Can it be avoided?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Isn't access to `/dev/random` involved, at least in the constructor call?

Comment: @cls Sure. But the point is only about incidentally about performance (I was just correcting the misconception about virtual function performance as a side-note): in your case `virtual` is **meaningless**. *That’s* why you shouldn’t use it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair enough, but I'm actually interested in the overhead which is produced by access to `/dev/random`. Is it only in the constructor, or each time `generate` is called?

Comment: @cls That’s an interesting question – but completely different from what you originally asked. I cannot find anything in the standard which specifies this. The stdlibc++ implementation that ships with GCC 4.7.2, however, reads the file for each random number that is requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload of `uniform_int_distribution::operator()` that accepts a `const param_type &`:

```
int64_t RandomInteger::generate(int64_t lower, int64_t upper) {
    int64_t i = this->distribution(this->randomEngine,
      std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t>{lower, upper}.param());
    return i;
}
```

(Note that you should value-initialize `distribution`, as you are not interested in setting its `param`.  Also, `distribution` should be templated with `int64_t`, not int.)

If `uniform_int_distribution` preserves any state, then this will use it efficiently.

In actual fact, most implementations of `uniform_int_distribution` do not preserve any state; see e.g. libstdc++ random.tcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a01001_source.html#l00832